# Trigonometry - represent as product: $1 + 2\cos\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

Represent the following as a product: $1 + 2\cos\alpha$

Please help if someone can solve this?

Comment: People are always happier if you give some information on what you’ve tried; or what you know; or where you got this question, as whether perhaps it was school-work.

Comment: I know, but my friend asked me to post this problem here and he didn't send any other information.

Comment: $$1+2\cos\alpha = 1\times (1+2\cos\alpha)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\equiv \frac \alpha 2$

Then
\begin{align}
1+2\cos(2x) &= 1+2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x) \\
  &= 1+2(\cos^2x-(1-\cos^2x)) \\
  &= 4\cos^2x-1 \\
  &= (2\cos x+1)(2\cos x-1) \\
  &= \left (2\cos \left(\frac \alpha 2\right )+1\right )\left (2\cos \left(\frac \alpha 2\right )-1\right ).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Note

$$1+2\cos a =2(\cos\frac\pi3+\cos a) =4\cos\frac{\pi+3a}6 \cos\frac{\pi-3a}6
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @err or - you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

$$1+2\cos\alpha = 1+2\cdot\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\alpha}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac {\alpha}{2}}\\=\frac{1+\tan^2\frac{\alpha}{2} +2(1-\tan^2\frac{\alpha}{2})}{\sec^2\frac{\alpha}{2}} \\=\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2} \left(3-\tan^2\frac{\alpha}{2}\right) $$

Comment: Thank you very much!!